# how to highlight entire week when we pick a date in that week using ng prime calendar

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to add enhancements to the ng prime calendar by picking a date will get the entire week highlighted. I am not able to do that.Could some help me in solving my problem.

[image]

Comment: did you try something

Comment: No i didn't get any idea of how to do that

Comment: Hey, how did you change the color of the highlighted date i.e. 17th Jan? I want to change it to #1D9DBE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by using `range` mode. The value bound to ngModel will be an array of length 2, containing the start and end values.

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="values" selectionMode="range" (onSelect)="select($event)"></p-calendar>
```

You can then bind to the `onSelect` event, calculate the start and end days, and set them into the array;

```
select(evt) {
    let start = new Date(evt);
    start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay());
    this.values[0] = start;

    let end = new Date(start);
    end.setDate(start.getDate() + 6); 
    this.values[1] = end;
  }
```

Here is a StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-rqr42n?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: In your code its not highlighting the entire week,  when we select a date in that week. Instead of that its counting 6 more days after that date.

Comment: Hang on, I thought you wanted a week from the selected date. Do you actually want it selected, so that in your screenshot it would be 14th - 20th?

Comment: yes and even if i select any date b/w 14-20 also it should highlight 14th-20th.

Comment: My bad. Answer and stackblitz are updated. Is that more what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Yes that is what i'm looking for but when i select a date b/w 1-6. Its not highlighting the entire week.What should i need to do in order to achieve that?

Comment: My bad, I've made another change, try that. The week won't highlight in blue if it falls outside of the current month (seems to be a primeng thing) but the start and end date will be

Comment: what property should i add if i want  to highlight entire week when i hover on a date in that week?

Comment: PrimeNG doesn't expose any EventEmitter for hover, so there's no simple way of doing it...

Comment: @arun Actually, you may as well use CSS for this. If you add the following rule, and just set background-color to whatever you want `:host ::ng-deep tr:hover td a {background-color: #ccc;}`. I've updated the StackBlitz again if you want to check it out

Comment: May i know the property that i need to use to auto close the calendar as soon as i clicked that date in a week?